# Retain State of TextView Color

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, data-persistence

I'm rendering some **TextViews** on a **LinearLayout**. These **TextViews** hold times that a user can select. If the user selects it, the **TextView's** color is set to green. If the user selects the **TextView** (time) again, then it reverts to grey.

So the behavior should be: If **TextView** unselected, remain grey. If **TextView** selected, become green. These **TextViews** should only change color on the user press.

I've managed to retain the state of the **TextView's** color whenever I scroll on the **LinerLayout**. However, if I press back, and leave the activity, the **TextViews** are all reset to grey.

Is it possible to save the instance of the **LinearLayout**, and it's elements with **Firestore**? Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to save the instance of the LinearLayout and its elements with Firestore?

No, this is not possible. The LinearLayout is not a [supported data-type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). What can you do instead, is to store the state of your button in Firestore and [keep it always in sync with the server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) using an EventListener. So every time you select the TextView, update the state on the server. If you leave the activity and you open it again, read the last updated value from the server.